# can't seem to find what's wrong with my $_POST

Tags: php, session, post

So I'm trying out sessions and this is how my code looks like:

```
session_id($username);
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['time_logged_in'] = time();
$_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['user[name]'];
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php"> 
    <table>
    <!--Text input for login-->
    <tr><td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type = 'TEXT'
           name = 'user[name]'
           value = '<?php  if(isset($_POST["user"])) {$tmp = $_POST["user"]; echo $tmp["name"]; } ?>'></td></tr>
```

I've tried a combination of $_POST['user'] and $_POST['user']['name']

error code:
Notice: Undefined index: user[name] in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_3\login.php on line 22

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is this `name = 'user[name]'`? What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: What is the value of `$username` ? I'm asking because the docs states that the ID of session_id had to have only: a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and - (minus)

Comment: I'm trying to get the user name from my post.  Using that information I want to link it to a session, so that I can welcome the user after they login.

Comment: `$_POST['user']['name']` was correct for accessing it if your submitted form contained a `<input name="user[name]"` field. But again, what's the purpose of nesting it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is a map (associative array) that contains key/value strings - not objects, 
so lines like:

```
$tmp = $_POST["user"]; 
echo $tmp["name"];
```

and:

```
$_POST['user[name]'];
```

won't work.

Further, when you assign the `name` property with value like: `user[name]` - when the form is submitted it'll pass encoded : `user%5Bname%5D` - so don't do that: use simple `name`s for the `input` fields in your HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, it appears you mean to be using your session variables instead of post.

You have:

```
value = '<?php  if(isset($_POST["user"])) {$tmp = $_POST["user"]; echo $tmp["name"]; } ?>'></td></tr>
```

And it should be:

```
value = '<?php  if(isset($_SESSION["userName"])) {echo $_SESSION["userName"]; } else { echo ''; } ?>'></td></tr>
```

Comment: I guess I could try this out.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to start your session before calling any session .
Your page must start with session_start();
And you can't really mess up with code Like you did .
Post more code please.

Comment: The `session_id` docs states thet it must be before the session start :http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php